# FOSUserBundle When does SECURITY_IMPLICIT_LOGIN event gets fired?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I've read [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/FOSUserEvents.php) and you can see the following:

```
/**
 * The SECURITY_IMPLICIT_LOGIN event occurs when the user is logged in programmatically.
 *
 * This event allows you to access the response which will be sent.
 * The event listener method receives a FOS\UserBundle\Event\UserEvent instance.
 */
const SECURITY_IMPLICIT_LOGIN = 'fos_user.security.implicit_login';
```

I've also read [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/EventListener/LastLoginListener.php) where you can read:

```
"Added an event when logging the user in implicitly"
```

What I don't understand is in plain english when that event gets fired. Is it when the user is remembered? I noticed that if you copy the url of my password protected website and close the browser tab, open a new tab and paste the url back, the user is still logged (which is ok) but no logging actually occurs (FOSUserBundle does not update the "lastLogin" field of the User entity). Ok, I understand this is because the session was already open...cool...sooooooo when does that event occur exactly, considering that the event (and method) that gets called when the user signs in "normally" is

```
SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN => 'onSecurityInteractiveLogin'
```

Thank you!

SN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search on the [github repo](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=SECURITY_IMPLICIT_LOGIN) show that the only time it is dispatched is in the [FOS\UserBundle\EventListener\AuthenticationListener](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/ef7ca325929ff102fff521653a2e3b88c7a40361/EventListener/AuthenticationListener.php).

This shows that the `fos_user.security.implicit_login` would be triggered after registration completion/confirmation and password reset completion (providing the user is enabled and can be logged in).

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly like this :)